# Deriving Fizeau's velocity equation with special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I can't get to the equation Fizeau found experimentally,

$u = \frac{c}{\mu} + v(1-\frac{1}{\mu^2})$,

Using special relativity. In particular, where does that minus sign come from?! I have done:

$$
\begin{align}
u & = \frac{u'+v}{1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}} \\
& = \frac{\frac{c}{\mu}+v}{1+\frac{v}{\mu c}} \\
& = \frac{c}{\mu}(\frac{1+\frac{\mu v}{c}}{1+\frac{v}{\mu c}})
\end{align}
$$

For this to work out, for some reason
$$
\frac{c}{\mu}(\frac{1+\frac{\mu v}{c}}{1+\frac{v}{\mu c}}) = \frac{c}{\mu}[1+\frac{v}{c}(\mu - \frac{1}{\mu})]
$$.

And I really don't see why that's the case. Something to do with $v<<c$, I think? How do I complete the derivation?

Comment: You have to assume that $\frac{\mu v}{c} << 1$ and expand the denominator by it's small value approximation, $\frac{1}{1+x} \approx 1 - x$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to assume that $v/c << 1$ and expand the denominator by it's small value approximation, $\frac{1}{(1+\ v /\mu c)} ≈1 −  v/\mu c$, ignoring terms $(v/c)^2$ (refractive indices are usually of order unity so it doesn't affect  the expansion) and higher, then the expression for $u$ becomes
$u \approx \frac{c}{\mu}({1+\frac{\mu v}{c}}) (1 -\frac{v}{\mu c})$

Notice that this is an approximation now (perhaps that what the confusion was?). Upon expanding the brackets you get
$\frac{c}{\mu} (1 + \frac{\mu v}{c} - \frac{v}{\mu c} -  (\frac{v}{c})^2)$ and you ignore the $(v/c)^2$ term for consistency.